# ECL integration

Tags: web8.5, ecl

I checked the documentation for SDL Web 8.5

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-65C7C3D0-E0AD-4CFF-9F7F-2AD327DA3904.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-9859C89E-3333-4AA1-B4D9-CA5F5163EEB7

I downloaded the example project and is a project created in 2012. Is this the last version or there is a new version for 8.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I think It will still work for 8.5 too unless if there are any API changes in Vimeo.

You can refer to @Bart Koopman [Flickr provider source code](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider/trunk/Flickr%20ECL%20Provider) example which I did test in 8.5 it's working fine.

I hope it helps

Comment: ECL has excellent backwards compatibility, so even when new features are introduced or API methods change, old providers continue to work without needing to be recompiled.